# AWS Instance with Best Network Performance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a spring boot REST service which uses Tomcat container in AWS ( instance type m4.xlarge, same region, non public facing, nothing on-prem, using private IPs). Our performance testing showed network latency, and scaling out hasn't shown any improvement and so I am also thinking of scaling up. In order to get maximum network benefit and throughput, which instance type will benefit me the most?

https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/

Will using a placement group help to boost TPS of my Rest API.

Comment: Can you add a bit more information, Are you trying to access from public internet? AWS internally? Across regions ?

Answer (score 0):

You can view the "network performance" of each instance type on the page you linked... Look at the "Instance Types Matrix" table on that page. The m4.xlarge has "High" network performance.

Make sure [Enhanced Networking](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/enhanced-networking.html) is enabled on your instance.

A placement group would only reduce latency between other instances that are in the same placement group. You don't specify what type of communication you are seeing a latency issue with. Is it latency between EC2 instances? If it is between EC2 instances, are they in the same availability zone and are you making sure to use private IPs? Please provide more details if you want more help.

Comment: Our client has set of instances calling our service API (scaled out to 5 instance) in the same AZ. The latency is observed when the client calls service, I am proposing putting client and service API instances in a placement group. Added few more details to my question. Thank you.

Comment: @HimalayMajumdar the client and API servers are currently both in the same AWS account, in the same VPC? Are you sure you are using the private IPs of the API servers to reference them from the client?

Comment: Yes, same vpc and subnet. Our service rest api instances are fronted by classic elb which clients are invoking

Comment: Are you using an internal facing ELB or an external facing ELB? You should be using an internal facing ELB and make sure that the ELB and instances are in the same AZ(s).

Comment: internal facing ELB

Comment: It sounds like you are doing everything correct. I'm not sure a placement group is going to help since traffic is going through the ELB. How much latency are you seeing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137374/discussion-between-himalay-majumdar-and-mark-b).